# Windows Server 2003 + WMI = Regular Bluescreens

Tags: windows-server-2003, wmi, bsod

I have serious problems with machines running Windows Server 2003 x64 Edition. I've written an application which queries periodically the system status using the WMI database. The database is opened/closed for each request separately to make sure that any memory it has used get's free'd asap.

Anyway, from time to time, these systems get an bluescreen (in most cases with code 0x0000009c). A look into the Event Viewer tells me that WMIxWDM was the last thing that happened (error) before the system crashed. This is not happening on all 2003 servers, and it does not happen on 2008/2008R2 systems.

Are there known issues about that? The systems are kept up-to-date and have latest updates and drivers installed.

Answer (score 2):

try running a memory diagnostic.  0x0000009c is the stop code for a hardware error being reported from the processor (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162363). Typically transient errors like this are related to memory.